# Can't get 100% Height to work on Wrapper. html, body and outer wrapper are at 100% need visible overflow

Tags: html, css, wordpress

**Solved** : had to float the #main div, plus quite a lot of other major changes to the structure. But the coup-de-gras was the float.

The site in question can be viewed at http://thepremium.ca/amodestblog

Problem is I need the #main div to have a visible overflow in order to show the date divs that are -positioned to the left, outside the visible div.

If I set the overflow (which is currently hidden) I lose my background color because the div shrinks down to about 20px in height. 100% doesn't work.

I traced it back to a problem with the #wrapper div which is also not taking to the 100% height which it is assigned, which isn't making a lot of sense because the #wrapper-background div it is inside is adopting the full height of the browser, along with  and

Hopefully someone can come up with a solution to this one. Please view the source on the site itself, I've got too many different css files (using wordpress thematic theme) to put all the different css in here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could change the ribbon-front div to fixed position and then use left and top to position the div where you want it.

```
.dateRibbon .ribbon-front {
  background-color: #84C036;
  height: 55px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 71px;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50;   // You'd have to work out what the exact values should be.
  left: 70; 
}
```

Otherwise I'd restructure the page to ensure the date ribbon was not a child of the #main div.

Comment: Could do but unfortunately its dynamic content so the ribbon gets displayed beside a post, I can't know before hand how many and at what height the different ribbons would be, so if i used a fixed div they'd all tile on top of each other. Good point though on placing it outside the main div. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Just realized I can't put it outside the #main div, its part of a loop :( :( :( Anybody pleasee?!

Comment: Still quite hacky, but what about giving #main a fixed pixel height then such as 'height: 650px;'. Won't work if you need the screen to stretch, but maybe just set a very large height.